# Can a group be isomorphic to a group that does not have an element of the same order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a finite abelian group of order $180$.  By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups:

$G \sim \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$

$G \sim \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{3^2} \times  \mathbb Z_{5}$

$G \sim \mathbb Z_{2^2} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$

$G \sim \mathbb Z_{2^2} \times \mathbb Z_{3^2} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$

Only the groups $\mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$ and $\mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{3^2} \times  \mathbb Z_{5}$ have elements of order $18$.  I also know that in an isomorphism elements of the same order are mapped to each other.  Then how can $G$ be isomorphic to groups that have an element of order $18$ and groups that do not have an element of order $18$?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$ doesn't have an element of order $18$. Specifically, it has no element of order $9$. However, $\mathbb Z_{2^2} \times \mathbb Z_{3^2} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the theorem wrong. It says that if $G$ is an abelian group of order 180, then it must be isomorphich to one of the 4 given subgroups, not to all of them.

Anyway to note that two isomoprhic groups have to have a element of same order use the fact that if $a^n = 1$ in $G_1$ and $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ is group isomorphism, then $1 = \phi(1) \phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n$. If $k<n$ is order of $\phi(a)$, then we have that $1 = \phi(a)^k = \phi(a^k) \implies a^k = 1$, which is impossible.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.  Can it be isomorphic to 2 groups or just 1?

Comment: Isomorphism is an equivalence relation.  If one group is isomorphic to two others, they are isomorphic between themselves and are in this sense the same group.  No two of the four you listed are isomorphic, which you can tell by considering elements of order $4$ and $9$, so G cannot be isomorphic to two of them.